# How to check option selected in one drop-down is selected or not in another drop-down

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple number of dropdown with same class name, if i am selecting one option in one dropdown, how to check that option is selected or not in other dropdowns.

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <select class="drop">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>                                               
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <select class="drop">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>                                               
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <select class="drop">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>                                               
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <table>
```

This is my jquery

```
$(document).on('change', '.drop', function () {
var value = $(this).val();
});
```

I am stuck with this point how to check the selected var value is selected or not in another dropdown.

Comment: You can just add various selectors (classes ot ids) to your `<select>` or try to use js `.index()` or css `eq` pseudoclass.

Comment: @Oleg Nurutdinov. Thanks, Using different id's is possible but I am trying to do with the same class name. with .index() how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop all .drop select excluding the current one and check their value :

```
$(document).on('change', '.drop', function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  // initialize bool
  var selected_in_other_dropdowns = false;
  // loop all .drop excluding this one
  $('.drop').not(this).each(function() {
    if($(this).val() == value) {
      // same value found
      selected_in_other_dropdowns = true;
    }
  });
  if(selected_in_other_dropdowns === true) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You check like this.

Loop over other `.drop` class, and compare the selected value with other dropdown value.

```
$(document).on('change', '.drop', function () {
var value = $(this).val();
 $('.drop').not(this).each(function(index,val){
   if(val.value == value) {
     console.log('already selected');
     // now do whatever you want.
   }
 })
});
```

[**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eQbvpp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with just jquery selector and without looping as follow:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.drop', function () {
var value = $(this).val();
var same_selected = $(".drop").not(this).find(`option[value="${value}"]:selected`)
if (same_selected.length<=0) console.log("No Match")
else console.log(`there is ${same_selected.length} Match with current selection !`)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <select class="drop">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>                                               
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <select class="drop">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>                                               
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>
        <select class="drop">
        <option value="1">A</option>
        <option value="2">B</option>
        <option value="3">C</option>                                               
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <table>
```